# get a column based on values of 2 columns SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with many columns, out of these, two columns i am interested in.

These 2 column may have values like `(p,p)(a,p)(p,a)(a,a)`.

Based on what values are present in these columns collectively, i want to display a third column as `1,0.5,0.5,0` for the cases mentioned above respectively.

eg table:

```
column1 column2 column3
   p       p        1
   p       a       0.5
   a       p       0.5
   a       a        0
```

how can this be done. i tried a lot but to no avail. plz help.

Comment: i did. but can v test for 2 column values in case stmt. lemme look

Comment: Although most probably not relevant for this question, you should always add the appropriate tag for the DBMS you are using ( `postgresql`, `oracle`, ...)

Comment: yes, it will help you to get the correct syntax as all DBMS have different syntax

Comment: I'LL KEEP THAT IN MIND a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the example using CASE statement which examines values in both columns and returns the required value in the third column.

```
CASE WHEN column1 = 'p' AND column2 = 'p' THEN 1
     WHEN (column1 = 'a' AND column2 = 'p') OR (column1 = 'p' AND column2 = 'a') THEN 0.5
     WHEN column1 = 'a' AND column2 = 'a' THEN 0 END AS Column3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   column1, column2, 
     CASE 
         WHEN column1 = p AND column2 = p THEN 1
         WHEN column1 = a AND column2 = a THEN 0
         ELSE 0.5
      END AS column3
FROM Production.Product
```

Here you go